# java.lang.SecurityException AWSCredentialsProvider Signer Information Does Not Match

Tags: java, aws-sdk

I am using 2 Amazon-provided libraries: `redshift-jdbc42-1.2.27.1051` and `aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.600`. Both libraries define a class `AWSCredentialsProvider` under package `com.amazonaws.auth`. When I'm trying to use my app, I get this Exception:

`Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: class "com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProvider"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package`

I am not sure how to resolve this. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that on Amazon's documentation for the Redshift JDBC driver, they say:

> If you use the Amazon Redshift JDBC driver for database
>   authentication, you must have AWS SDK for Java 1.11.118 or later in
>   your Java class path. If you don't have AWS SDK for Java installed,
>   you can use a driver that includes the AWS SDK.

The issue was arising from the fact that now I have AWS SDK components provided by both libraries. Now, I don't need the AWS SDK packaged with the driver, since I can use it from the AWS S3 SDK. In fact, Amazon encourages developers to use a Redshift JDBC driver without a pre-packaged SDK:

> **Important**
>
> We strongly recommend using an Amazon Redshift JDBC driver that
>   **doesn't include the AWS SDK** if possible.

If you run into this problem and are downloading the dependency from Maven, you can find a non-aws-sdk driver here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazon.redshift/redshift-jdbc42-no-awssdk

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.***.jar which is mentioned in Athena's jdbc jar file. To find athena's sdk version, extract AthenaJDBC42.jar file, you can find the version in pom file \AthenaJDBC42\META-INF\maven\com.amazonaws\aws-java-sdk-core\pom.properties.

```
#Generated by Maven
#Tue Jun 02 12:03:54 IST 2020
**version=1.11.793**
groupId=com.amazonaws
artifactId=aws-java-sdk-core
```

Use the same version of aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.793.jar while connecting to S3 bucket would solve that issue.