# Connecting to Athena using JDBC driver from a Spring Java application

Tags: java, amazon-s3, jdbc, simba

I am trying to connect to Athena via latest (2.16) JDBC driver jar from a Java Spring web application. The application also connects to S3 to upload files there. I am seeing this exception when bean for s3 client is being instantiated on addition of the Athena JDBC jar.

I tried upgrading aws-java-sdk-core to 1.11.793 and also latest 1.11.998 as suggested in this post, but it is not helping
[java.lang.SecurityException AWSCredentialsProvider Signer Information Does Not Match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57260883/java-lang-securityexception-awscredentialsprovider-signer-information-does-not-m)

```
Caused by: com.simba.athena.support.exceptions.GeneralException: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/https://forums.aws.amazon.com/(100191) Failed to create AWS Credentials Provider class: com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.
+ ... 61 more+
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain
+ at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~?:1.8.0_221+
+ at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~?:1.8.0_221+
+ at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~?:1.8.0_221+
+ at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~?:1.8.0_221+
+ at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264) ~?:1.8.0_221+
+ at com.simba.athena.athena.utilities.AJUtilities.createAwsCredentialsProvider(Unknown Source) ~AthenaJDBC42.jar:?+
```

This is the exact issue I am facing -
[Athena JDBC driver version 2.0.15 not compatible with core AWS SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64990001/athena-jdbc-driver-version-2-0-15-not-compatible-with-core-aws-sdk)